# A question on simple $P_{\aleph_2}$-points

Tags: set-theory, forcing, ultrafilters, cardinal-characteristics

This question is motivated by discussion surrounding [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351827/a-new-cardinal-characteristic-related-to-partitions).

An ultrafilter $U$ on $\omega$ is a simple $P_{\aleph_2}$-point if it is generated by a sequence $\langle X_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_2\rangle$ such that

$$\alpha<\beta\Longrightarrow |X_\beta\setminus X_\alpha|<\aleph_0,$$

that is, generated by an $\omega_2$ sequence of subsets of $\omega$ that is decreasing modulo the ideal of finite sets.

**Question**

Is the existence of a simple $P_{\aleph_2}$-point consistent with $\mathfrak{b}=\aleph_1$?

Comment: Did you mean $\beta < \alpha$?

Comment: Fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "yes".  Alan Dow pointed out in correspondence that the construction of Blass and Shelah referenced below can be modified to yield such a model.  The particular model arises by using finite support to add an $\omega_1$-sequence of Cohen reals, followed by a finite support iteration adding the generating set for the $P_{\aleph_2}$-point using a variant of Mathias forcing.  The salient point of the construction is that the Mathias-type forcing (really Mathias forcing with respect to a carefully chosen ultrafilter at each stage) does not add a real dominating the Cohen reals, and so $\mathfrak{b}=\aleph_1$ in the extension.

Referring to the discussion on the [question of Banakh](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351827/a-new-cardinal-characteristic-related-to-partitions) that motivated our question, this shows there is a model in which Banakh's cardinal $\kappa$ is strictly greater than $\mathfrak{b}$, as the $P_{\aleph_2}$-point is an ultrafilter $U$ with $\tau(U)=\aleph_2$.

*Blass, Andreas; Shelah, Saharon*, [**Ultrafilters with small generating sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02764864), Isr. J. Math. 65, No. 3, 259-271 (1989). [ZBL0681.03033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0681.03033).

Comment: Great! I only now noticed this your very helpful post. Thank you.

Comment: Is it true that $\aleph_2=\mathfrak c$ (or at least $\aleph_2$ can be equal to $\mathfrak c$) in your model?

Comment: What is the value of $\mathrm{cov}(\mathcal M)$ in your model? Can it be equal to $\aleph_1$? This would help to shed light to another my question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/352976/61536